# PDF generation issue in java code

Tags: java, pdf, soap

I am getting a PDF attachment in a Soap response message.  I need to generate a PDF back out of it.  However, the generated PDF is of the following form:

```
%PDF-1.4
%
2 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width
278/Length 7735/Height 62/Filter/DCTDecode>>stream
```

How can I solve this issue?

Here is the code showing how I am embedding a PDF as an attachment:

```
message = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
header.detachNode();
AttachmentPart attachment1 = message.createAttachmentPart();
fr = new FileReader(new File(pathName));
br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String stringContent = "";
line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    stringContent = stringContent.concat(line);
    stringContent = stringContent.concat("\n");
    line = br.readLine();
}
fr.close();
br.close();
attachment1.setMimeHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
attachment1.setContent(stringContent, "application/pdf");
```

The below code describes how I am getting PDF back from the SOAP message:

```
Object content = attachment1.getContent();
writePdf(content);

private void writePdf(Object content) throws IOException, PrintException,
        DocumentException {
    String str = content.toString();
    //byte[] b = Base64.decode(str);
    //byteArrayToFile(b);
    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File
            (AppConfig.getInstance().getConfigValue("webapp.root") +
            File.separator + "temp" + File.separator + "hede.pdf"));
    //String s2 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    //System.out.println("S2::::::::::"+s2);
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);

    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph(str));
    document.close();
    file.close();
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: So how do you embed the PDF in your SOAP message? Is in an `xsd:base64` binary tag or `MTOM` based? Please should that part of the WSDL.

Comment: You should provide more details like Which framework, language you are using for the above mentioned problem. Also what is the environment you have like users are accessing the link and that triggers call to webservice etc. This will help others to give solution.

Comment: I support the call for more information. At first glance, though, it looks like you read the PDF as if it was text and you furthermore could ignore line breaks and non ASCII characters. PDF is a binary format and has to be treated accordingly.

Comment: Can anybody suggest me the answer please.I am stuck with it from past 3 days

Comment: @APerson After your edit the quoted PDF content head looks quite different from what the original question said. Are you sure that your change represents the problem of user2011353? Furthermore you now talk about generating a PDF out of the response. the original question seemed to indicate that there already was a PDF in the response and only had to be extracted...

Comment: @mkl First, the original markup looked quite different from the original HTML; just look at the edit I made and select "Side by Side Markdown".  Second, the original question shows that the user wanted to somehow "get" a PDF out of the response.  The initial edit shows that the user placed the words "get" and "generate" side-by-side.

Comment: @APerson241 Ouch, indeed, the PDF dictionary content already had been there, it simply had not been visible. Now I really wonder why user user2011353 left it like that when creating his question... <sigh>.

Answer (score 1):

There are several faults in the supplied code:

In *the code showing how you are embedding pdf as an attachment,* you are using a `Reader` (a `FileReader` enveloped in a `BufferedReader`) to read the file to attach line by line, concat these lines with using `\n` as separator, and send the result of the concatenation as attachment content of type "application/pdf".

This is a procedure you may consider for text files (even though it isn't a good choice there either) but binary files read like this most like get broken beyond repair (and PDFs **are** binary files, in spite of a phase early in their history where handling them as text was quite harmless):

- When reading a file, a `Reader` interprets the bytes in it according to some character encoding (as none is given explicitly here, most likely the platform default encoding is used) to transform them to Unicode characters collected in a `String`. Already here most likely the binary data is damaged.
- When using `readLine` you read these Unicode characters until the `Reader` recognizes a line break. *A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.* (Java API sources JavaDocs). When you continue to concatenate these lines uniformly using `\n` as separators, you essentially replace all single carriage return characters and all carriage return - line feed character pairs into single line feed characters, damaging the binary data even further.
- When you make the attachment API you use encode this string as the content of some attachment part, you make it transform your Unicode characters back into bytes. If by chance the same character encoding is assumed as was by the Reader before, this might heal some of the damage done back then, but surely not all, and the line break interpretation of the step inbetween certainly isn't healed, either. If a different encoding is used, the data is damaged once again.

Thus, check what other arguments your AttachmentPart.setContent methods accept, choose something which does not damage binaries (e.g. InputStreams, ByteBuffers, byte[], ...) and use that, e.g. a FileInputStream.

The *code which describes how you are getting PDF back from SOAP message* is even weirder... You assume that toString of the attachment content returns some meaningful string representation (very unlikely here), and then continue to **create** a new PDF containing that string representation as text content of the first and only paragraph of the PDF. Thus while your attachment creation code discussed above at least 'merely' damaged the PDF, your attachment restrieval code completely ignores the nature of the attachment and destroys it beyond recognition.

You should instead check the actual type of the content object, retrieve the binary data it holds according to its type, and store that content using a FileOutputStream (not a Writer, and not using Strings inbetween, and not copying 'line' by 'line').

And whatever source gave you the impression that your code was appropriate for the task... well, either you completely misunderstood it or you should shun it from now on.